# fontawesome icon height and width coming as 0 in the browser

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

My Web app is using font awesome latest version (6.1.1) and it is working perfectly as I'm adding fontawesome icons. Now I added a new icon whose height and width are coming as zero in the browser. Code is:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-xmark" aria-hidden="true"> 
    </i>
        Delete
</button>
```

`<i>` is coming as 0 width and height. Any ideas why? A screenshot showing this problem is attached [here](https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=504671634160).

Thanks

Comment: On the font awesome docs, they seem to suggest [`<i class="fa-solid fa-trash-xmark"></i>`](https://fontawesome.com/icons/trash-xmark?s=solid). Maybe try that instead of fa? Also this seems to be a pro only icon, so it won't be there if you're running the free version.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the `i` element display `inline-block` with some height and width.

```css
i{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 1rem;
    width: 1rem;
}
```

If this does not work, then, there is problem elsewhere. If it does work, check your stylesheet to see if there is an overflow or layout problem.

Comment: I thought font awesome used ```font-size``` for css sizing their icons not width and height?

Comment: @seriously Yes, they do. But for OP, the icons are not appearing at all. So there must be an issue with layout structure.

Comment: yeah, but I'm pretty sure OP is trying to access a paid icon for free :))